# Javascript automation for files move into another folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, gruntjs, npm

I have a folder in my server which contains some files. These are automated that means everyday we get new files automatically which will overwrite the old ones. So want to take a back up for this data. How can i copy all these files in to a another folder by renaming the files with current date while copying.

Ex : I have a folder named folder1 which contains 4 files. Path for this folder is `home/webapps/project1/folder1`

```
aaa.csv
bbb.csv
ccc.csv
ddd.csv
```

Now I want to copy all these four files in to a different folder named `folder2`. Path for this folder is `home/webapps/project1/folder2`. While copying these files I want to rename each file and add the current date to the file. So my file names in `folder2` should be..

```
aaa091012.csv
bbb091012.csv
ccc091012.csv
ddd091012.csv
```

I want to write a script for this using Javascript. Please give me some idea or some sample scripts related to this.

Comment: This is tagged `gruntjs`. Does the solution need to use grunt?

Comment: @positlabs yeah if we use grunt it would be great

Comment: I assume you searched npmjs.org and tried the things that you found? What were they and how were they not good enough?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I am new to node can you help me with it...

Comment: search npmjs.org - it lets you find all the things that are immediately installed for use in your nodejs project. Need `node-cron`? `npm install node-cron` and done, in your source code you can now say `require("node-cron")` in the same way you require basic Node.js APIs

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans is it possible to zip it and unzip it to by automation

Comment: what do you mean with "it" when you say "zip it"? Node.js comes with `npm`, which is the package manager for libraries that you find on npmjs.org, and allows for a package.json file that indicates, amongst other things, dependencies that will get automatically installed when you run the command `npm install` from the project directory.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I need to open the config file and change the installer value and execute the .exe file

For example in the config file i have value like this 
PPP.install= iphone

I need to change it to 

PPP.install= android

Comment: If you use a `.json` config file instead of an `.ini` config file, you can do all the reading, manipulation, and writing that you like, when you like. Node.js lets you `var myconfig = require('./confige.json')` and will give you the object that JSON file encodes so you can do things like `PPP = myconfig.PPP` and `myconfig.PPP = ...` etc, and writing an update to it back to file is just a matter of `fs.writeFile('./config.json', JSON.stringify(myconfig))`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans but my type of file is propertie file will it workout

Comment: if it *has* to be .ini, the first hit I got on npmjs.org is https://www.npmjs.com/package/ini

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans but they save it as .properties file not sure what to do :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

function dateFormat(){
    var date = new Date();
    var year  = (date.getFullYear() + '').slice(2);
    var month = (date.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? '0' + (date.getMonth() + 1) : (date.getMonth() + 1);
    var day   = date.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + date.getDate() : date.getDate();
    return year+month+day;
}
function moveAndRename(sourceDir, destDir){
    fs.readdir(sourceDir, function(err, files){
        if(err)
            return err;
        else {
            files.forEach(function(file){
                var dotIndex = file.lastIndexOf(".");
                var name = file.slice(0, dotIndex);

                var newName = (name + dateFormat()) + path.extname(file);

                var read = fs.createReadStream(path.join(sourceDir, file));
                var write = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(destDir, newName));
                read.pipe(write);
            });
        }
    });
}

moveAndRename("/home/webapps/project1/folder1",
              "/home/webapps/project1/folder2")
```

You can use this npm lib: https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron, to do some  job autominate.

Comment: thanks for your reply...is there any tutorial how to execute the code and see

Comment: Just save this code in a file `copy.js`, then run `node copy.js`.

Comment: is it possible to zip the files and unzip it to by automation

Comment: I need to open the config file and change the installer value and execute the .exe file

For example in the config file i have value like this 
PPP.install= iphone

I need to change it to 

PPP.install= android

Comment: Perfect Answer for copy files from source to destination folder. Incase anyone wants to set destination folder dynamically, make sure you call this funcation before calling moveAndRename. fs.mkdirSync(destDir, { recursive: true });