# node automation for files move into another folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, backbone.js

- Is it possible to write the same shell script file in node js

  - providing my code below

  cd /home/webapps/project1/folder1
  for f in *.csv
  do 
     cp -v $f /home/webapps/project1/folder2/${f%.csv}$(date +%m%d%y).csv
  done

  - what I am trying to achieve is given below

I have a folder in my server which contains some files. These are automated that means everyday we get new files automatically which will overwrite the old ones. So want to take a back up for this data. How can i copy all these files in to a another folder by renaming the files with current date while copying.

Comment: Please see this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29404104/javascript-automation-for-files-move-into-another-folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example using `fs`

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    input_path = '/home/webapps/project1/folder1/',
    output_path = '/home/webapps/project1/folder2/';

fs.readdir(input_path, function(err, files) {
    var date = new Date();

    date = ('0' + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + ''
         + ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + ''
         + ('0' + (date.getFullYear())).slice(-2);

    files.forEach(function(file) {
        var name, extension;

        // Check for *.CSV files
        if (file.toLowerCase().indexOf('.csv') !== file.length - 4) return;

        name = file.substr(0, file.length - 4);
        extension = file.substr(-4);

        // Copy file
        fs.createReadStream(input_path + file).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(output_path + name + date + extension));
    });
});
```

Comment: can you tell me how to execute and see

Comment: just wrap code in `index.js` and run it with `node index.js`

Comment: is it possible to zip and unzip files

Comment: I guess so just search for `zip node` or `unzip node` in google